# spring, how to change cglib naming policy

Tags: java, spring, proxy-classes, cglib

When spring creates a proxy, it uses cglib with default naming policy. Is there any way to change the naming policy? Generated class names clash with another framework I use.

Comment: How is that possible? You have other framework which is using CGLib to enhance the same classes? Sounds like very strange setup.

Comment: it's not strange. i do integration tests when spring creates proxy for my session scoped bean. and also i have unit tests where i check business functionality of the same object

Comment: And what kind of errors are you getting? Seems that CGLib should be able to handle that. http://cglib.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/cglib/cglib/src/proxy/net/sf/cglib/core/DefaultNamingPolicy.java?view=markup

Comment: it's described here: http://blog.piotrturski.net/2013/06/codegenerationexception-and-proxies.html

Answer (score 2):

It seems cglib [claims](http://cglib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/net/sf/cglib/core/DefaultNamingPolicy.html) it can detect name clashes but for some reason it does not in this case.

Because of that problem (and your report?) the other framework you are using (catch-exception) [patched](https://code.google.com/p/catch-exception/issues/detail?id=10&can=1&q=label%3aRelease-1.1.0) their code to avoid it.

Comment: It can detect name clashes as long as *one* cglib is used. Since Spring 3.2+ repackages cglib, there easily can be *two* cglibs, each taking care of its own name collisions.